# ngTouch module prevent redirect to url from href attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch

Something wrong happens with my application on mobile devices. I have something like this:

```
<a href="#!/kategori/hva-skjer" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
```

This is one of link in menu. What I want and what works well on dekstop is closing menu and redirect to proper url from `href` attribute.

This wont working on mobile devices (on emulator in chrome devtools too). It's toggling the menu, but without redirection.

When I remove `ngTouch` module from dependencies in app bootstrap file, the problem dissapears.

Someone had similar situation and know already solution? Or it's a bug of ngTouch module?

### Demo

In your dev tools enable touch emualation and click on links. As you can see `toggle` function working when links not.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1TldHkHvVfo4OmH7MLk4?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still helpful, seeing as the question is over a year old, but I ran in the exact same issue recently. There seems to be a known bug concerning ngTouch. (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5307)

The solution that worked for me goes as follows :

Replace the content of your ng-touch file (angular-touch.js) with the file you can find [here](https://github.com/NorikDavtian/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngTouch/directive/ngClick.js). (This step might not be necessary for some, but for me it was for some reason.)

Then go into the file and change the following lines :

```
ngTouch.directive('ngClick', ['$parse', '$timeout', '$rootElement',
function($parse, $timeout, $rootElement) {
```

to :

```
ngTouch.directive('ngClick', ['$parse', '$timeout', '$rootElement', '$location',
function($parse, $timeout, $rootElement, $location) {
```

Then find this part :

```
    if (!angular.isDefined(attr.disabled) || attr.disabled === false) {
       element.triggerHandler('click', [event]);
     }
```

And add an if right below it like so :

```
if (!angular.isDefined(attr.disabled) || attr.disabled === false) {
       element.triggerHandler('click', [event]);
     }
if the element has an href attribute, ensure that the url gets updated.
   if (attr.href && angular.isString(attr.href)) {
    $location.url(attr.href);
   }
```

You could also stop using href and manually change your hrefs to the location.go() function, but this solution does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old bug, that wasn't fixed before this time. Href and ng-click doesn't work together.

Below you see how can you avoid this bug.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34612541/4245233