# in the 'ngTouch' module, the a link is prevented when it has a ng-Click directive

Tags: angularjs, events, click

use the angular 1.3.0.beta.2 and corresponding angular-touch.
i add a ng-Click directive to the '', this is my code:

the js

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch'])
```

the html

```
<a href="#/sameHash" ng-click="hideSide()" class="sideIcon">some hash</a>
```

when click the a tag ,the 'hideSide' function was runn,but the url didn't change.
if i remove the ngTouch module, it the 'hideSide' function run, and url change too.
i want to use the ngTouch module,how do i get the a link usefull with ngClick

Comment: There is open [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6001) of `ngTouch` with `ngClick`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngTouch module prevent redirect to url from href attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662375/ngtouch-module-prevent-redirect-to-url-from-href-attribute)